# Pico W – Async operation halts when accessing pio state machine registers

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

```
Pico W – Async operation halts when accessing pio state machine registers.

This project uses a Raspberry Pi – Pico W,  Thonny IDE.  Purpose of the project to count encoder pulse using PIO and operate other Async processes.  I have written two programs: Sync and Async.  Sync program works well.  Async stops at a certain place.  I am searching the internet for the answer.  Please review Async program below.  Possible method in Async portion of the program.


@asm_pio() 
def pulse_counter():
    
    label("loop")           # Start of the loop
    mov(isr, y)             # Move Y (which is (2^32 - 1 - the number of edges)) into the ISR
    push()                  # Push that value into the RX FIFO
    
    wait(0, pin, 0)         # wait for rising edge of input signal
    wait(1, pin, 0)
    jmp(y_dec, "loop")      # Jump back to the beginning and decrement Y.

# Create the state machine on the correct pin and start it, and initialise it.
pulse_counter_sm = StateMachine(0, pulse_counter, in_base=Pin(4)) #
pulse_counter_sm.active(1)
pulse_counter_sm.put(0xFFFFFFFF)  #sends this number to ISR

def movetest_forward():
    Mot_A_Forward.value(1)
    Mot_B_Forward.value(1)

def move_stop():
    Mot_A_Forward.value(0)
    Mot_B_Forward.value(0)

#Coroutine blink on a timer
async def blink(delay):     #Machine Heartbeat
    while True:
        led.toggle()
        await uasyncio.sleep(delay)
        
#Coroutine motion - motor oparation
async def motormotion(delay):
    
    while True:
  ****  pulses = pulse_counter_sm.get() ******This command halts async operation*****
        if(pulses == 4294967292):
            print("yes")
            move_stop()
        print("pulses",pulses)
        print("fifo_rx",pulse_counter_sm.rx_fifo())
        print("fifo_tx",pulse_counter_sm.tx_fifo())
        print("pulses",pulse_counter_sm.get())
        await uasyncio.sleep(delay) #leave coroutine
 
        
#Coroutine: entry point for asyncio program
async def main():
   
    #Start Coroutine as a task
    uasyncio.create_task(blink(0.5))
    
    #Start Coroutine as a motion
    uasyncio.create_task(motormotion(0.1))
    
    #Main Loop Robot Behaviors
    while True:
        #print("done")
        await uasyncio.sleep_ms(10)
    
#Start event loop and run entry point coroutine
uasyncio.run(main())
Pico W – Async operation halts when accessing pio state machine registers.

This project uses a Raspberry Pi – Pico W,  Thonny IDE.  Purpose of the project to count encoder pulse using PIO and operate other Async processes.  I have written two programs: Sync and Async.  Sync program works well.  Async stops at a certain place.  I am searching the internet for the answer.  Please review Async program below.  Possible method in Async portion of the program.
```

Search internet for dio and asyc example

Would like to get asyc and dio working well.

Pico W – Async operation halts when accessing pio state machine registers.
This project uses a Raspberry Pi – Pico W, Thonny IDE. Purpose of the project to count encoder pulse using PIO and operate other Async processes. I have written two programs: Sync and Async. Sync program works well. Async stops at a certain place. I am searching the internet for the answer. Please review Async program below. Possible method in Async portion of the program.